# How to include second last data from same table in sequalize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a history table that store data whenever other table store/update data. I need to retrieve specific data row from the history table with immediate previous data based on the `tableName` and `tableId` order by `createdOn` desc.

```
const { STRING, BOOLEAN, INTEGER } = require("sequelize");


module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const History = sequelize.define("history", {
        id: { type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
        tableName: { type: STRING },
        tableId: { type: STRING },
        data: { type: STRING },
        createdOn: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: true }
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
    })
    return History;
}
```

Expected response

```
{
    id: 10,
    tableName: product,
    tableId: 155,
    data: {some data},
    createdOn: 99999999,
    previousHistory: {
        id: 3,
        tableName: product,
        tableId: 155,
        data: {some data},
        createdOn: 7777777,
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show Sequelize queries you already tried.

Comment: I cannot find how the association works for this scenario. Then only I can think about the query.